# Castle dynamic proxy and INotifyPropertyChanged on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm wrapping my entities with a proxy using Castle DP, my entities implement by themselves INotifyPropertyChanged. and raise the event when set is called.

i wrote some unit test on the wrapping to see that the propertychanged event is fired when i manipulate entities through the proxy and they all passed.

the problem is on a real application with a screen, when i bind the screen to a property that is actually a DP, the screen registering to the propertychanged in a different way and it just doesn't work unless i implement a registration management inside the interceptor code

why this is the behavior, what does wpf do on the property that i don't when registering to property changed ?

Comment: By DP, do you mean Dynamic Proxy or Dependency Property?

Comment: Can you give some specifics in what you had to do to get it to work with dynamic proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In castle AOP there is one important thing to keep in mind - the `Equals` method is not working as you would expect.

Look here: [RRSL-Lite.EntityAOP](http://code.google.com/p/rrsl-lite/source/browse/#svn/trunk/EntityAop%253Fstate%253Dclosed). I had the same idea - to have AOP for INPC and created this library. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/rrsl-lite/source/browse/trunk/App.Test/RrslLiteTEST/EntityAopTEST.cs) is a simple sample of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy class generated as an Interface Proxy will have explicit interface implementations of properties and the WPF binding won't work unless it explictely matches.

The two solution are to change your binding paths to explicitely include the interface:

```
{Binding Path=(local:IEntity.ID)} instead of just {Binding ID}
```

or to use a virtual method proxy for your view models/entities and make any methods you intercept virtual.

Comment: The Binding is fine.. the problem is with the INPC

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact you are wrapping your *entities* with Castle's `CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget` method or similar. If you are relying on your *entities* to implement INPC and are relaying your `PropertyChanged` event hooks to the underlying proxy target, bear in mind when the `PropertyChanged` event is raised the `sender` will be your *entity* not your *proxy*. If you are trying to bind your proxy in WPF it will expect the `sender` to be the *proxy*. If not, it will ignore the change. The solution is to intercept the events and ensure you set the `sender` to be your *proxy*.